# How module bundlers like webpack, rollup, handle two different versions of same dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, rollup

If, module1 depends on button-component@1.0.2

and module2 depends on button-component@1.5.0

Which version of button-component is loaded in final bundle?

What steps can we take to avoid duplicate modules in final build?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> TL;DR: It is not the bundler. It is **Mostly** the package manager (NPM, etc.) that is responsible for providing dependencies which bundlers simply follow.

It is not really the bundler itself that working here. For third party dependencies, we are generally using NPM and thus `node_modules` in general.

Now job of the NPM is to keep dependency tree as flat as possible. Imagine following graph where `your-code` depends on `module1` and `module2`. And, `module1` itself is internally dependent on `module2`.

```
your-code <-- module1@1.0.0 <--- module2@1.0.5
          <-- module2@1.0.5
```

If `your-code` and `module1` uses same dependency, then `npm` will keep it flat under top-level `node_modules` folder and as such bundler (Webpack/Rollup) will pick single version of the `module`

Now imagine the other scenario:

```
your-code <-- module1@1.0.0 <--- module2@1.0.5
          <-- module2@2.0.0
```

Here `your-code` is using `module2` with version 2.0.0 but `module1` is using different version. That is a breaking change. In this case, npm will not keep it flat and install `module2@2.0.0` in you `node_modules` folder while `module2@1.0.5` will be installed in a `node_modules` folder of `module1`. The Bundler will pick both the version when it is bundling the code.

But it is not all that script. Usually if dependencies only differ at `patch` version i.e. last digit of **semver**, then `npm` will pick only one and ignore the other. Further, this resolution of dependencies also depends upon the NPM versioning model. You can specify lenient version of dependency using `^1.0.5` or `~1.0.5`. That also affect if [NPM will install modules separately or keep it flat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/5723098).

You can use [bundler analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) or equivalent to detect duplicate dependencies. When NPM was first released, it could not handle this and thus Bower was born to help developers with flat dependencies so that bundlers would pick only one version of dependency. But latest NPM is reasonably good enough for most cases and bower is no longer used.

---

Finally, I said **Mostly** because it is generally the package manager. But, in case of **bare** imports, you can teach/override bundler to specifically resolve from one and only one version. For example, consider Webpack resolution config below:

```
resolve: {
  // see below for an explanation
  alias: {
    preact: path.resolve('node_modules', 'preact')
  }
}
```

So, if you accidentally have `preact` more than once in your dependencies graph, then you can force Webpack to always use specific `preact` import from one specific folder.